# Emacs 24.3 python: Can't guess python-indent-offset, using defaults 4

Tags: python, python-2.7, emacs, elisp, indentation

Can anyone who understands Lisp please help resolve this warning?

I upgraded to Emacs 24.3 and whenever I create a Python file using Emacs I get this warning message. Searched in `python.el` and found the following section of code that produces the warning:

```lisp
(let ((indentation (when block-end
                     (goto-char block-end)
                     (python-util-forward-comment)
                     (current-indentation))))
  (if indentation
      (set (make-local-variable 'python-indent-offset) indentation)
    (message "Can't guess python-indent-offset, using defaults: %s"
             python-indent-offset)))
```

And here is my `.emacs` setup:

```lisp
(setq-default c-basic-offset   4
              tab-width        4
              indent-tabs-mode nil)

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
          (lambda ()
            (c-set-offset 'arglist-intro '+)
            (c-set-offset 'arglist-close 0)))

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (c-set-offset 'arglist-intro '+)
            (c-set-offset 'arglist-close 0)))
```

Comment: Don't quote your lambdas, it's at best useless.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When you open a python file, emacs guesses the indentation offset (number of spaces to indent) based on that file style.  When you **create** a file (the case you describe), emacs cannot guess (file is empty) so it uses your default (4) and notifies the user.

In other words: it is a harmless warning; if you find this is a bug please report it as such.

If you don't like emacs guessing the offset, customize the variable `python-indent-guess-indent-offset` to nil, and then emacs will use always your default (very unsafe in python, where indentation has meaning and you could be editing a file created by somebody else with other defaults).

Comment: You are right, this is very unsafe. However, sometimes it's very useful to change the whole file indentation to your default. How do you do that in a safe way?

Comment: @esilva, I would use autopep8 (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8) or maybe reindent (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Reindent/0.1.0), as far as my default was compliant with PEP8

Comment: If you don't like emacs *telling you* about its guessing the offset, customize the variable `python-indent-guess-indent-offset-verbose` to nil.

Comment: It's arguably a bug when the file is empty - the defaults are correct for the new file, almost by definition.  It would be fairly easy to add a test for `(< (point-min) (point-max))` around this code - I recommend you (@bohani) try it, and submit a patch!

Answer (score 15):

If all you want is to **silence the warnings**, while letting emacs still guess the offset as juanleon's answer explains, you can switch the `python-indent-guess-indent-offset-verbose` variable off.

```
(setq python-indent-guess-indent-offset t)  
(setq python-indent-guess-indent-offset-verbose nil)
```

Per [this comprehensive answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32940/how-to-detect-tabs-or-spaces-in-emacs) on the emacs SE.

Answer (score 0):

Look in `python.el`, not `python.elc`.  If you do not have `python.el`, then google for it (at least to look at it -- you do not need it to use Emacs).  `*.elc` is a byte-compiled file, which is pretty much incomprehensible to humans.

The source code, in `python.el`, will tell you just what `python-indent-guess-indent-offset` does, and hence why you see the result you see.

Comment: (let ((indentation
               (when block-end
                 (goto-char block-end)
                 (python-util-forward-comment)
                 (current-indentation))))
          (if indentation
              (set (make-local-variable 'python-indent-offset) indentation)
            (message "Can't guess python-indent-offset, using defaults: %s"
                     python-indent-offset)))))))

Comment: Got the above snapshot from python.el, could you please take a look? I don't quite understand lisp

Comment: Please see @juanleon's answer, which explains things well. The code looks for the current indentation as a guide, but if the file is empty then it has no guide, so it uses the default, 4. This message is just informative; it is not a *warning*.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers, and silencing the warning, this procedure deals with the problem and gives two examples for why the warning is useful.

Get a list of currently open buffers with `C-x C-b`. Filter those with a Python
extension, add quotes around them, and replace them in this command:

```el
(dolist (f '(
    "/path/to/file1"
    "/path/to/file2"
    ))
  (message (concat "Opening file: " f))
  (find-file (expand-file-name f)))
```

Execute the command (select the region, then `M-x evaluate-region`). Then `*Messages*` looks like this:

```
Opening file: /path/to/file1
Opening file: /path/to/file2
Can’t guess python-indent-offset, using defaults: 4
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
```

I had files I had used for testing and that I had forgotten, for example:

```py
from time import sleep

sleep(10000)
```

I only realized it thanks to this message and I deleted the files.

In another case, I had a useful file with just global variables, so I added this
line:

```py
# -*- mode: python; python-indent-offset: 4 -*-

SOME_GLOBAL_VAR = 0
```

Although this does set the buffer-local variable (check by changing to 6, then
checking the value with `C-h v python-indent-offset`), it only does so after the
warning message, not before. I decided to tolerate this message.